# Bundle install could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

When I type bundle install I got this error. I tried to find solution but nothing solve my case. Please help me.

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
      In Gemfile:
        rails (= 4.1.8) was resolved to 4.1.8, which depends on
          bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

      Current Bundler version:
        bundler (2.0.1)
    This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
    Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

    Could not find gem 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)', which is required by gem 'rails
    (= 4.1.8)', in any of the sources.

    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
      In Gemfile:
        rails (= 4.1.8)

        animate-rails was resolved to 1.0.10, which depends on
          rails
```

Comment: try after removing gemfile.lock

Comment: Thanks for your comment but nothing happened. The same error

Comment: rails 4.1.8 requires bundler ver < 2.0, you have 2.0.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your bundler gem is too big. You can downgrade for now by changing your gemfile to specify the lower version, and deleting the lock file again.

```
gem 'bundler', '1.17.1'
```

Then try these commands in the terminal

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.1
gem uninstall bundler -v 2.0.1
bundle update --bundler
bundle install
```

That last install command might be redundant. I'm on my phone so I can't test anything unfortunately.

Best of luck!

EDIT:

This is now a Heroku issue. Got it. Heroku docs regarding Bundler

> > **[Libraries](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#libraries)**
> > The following libraries are used by the platform for managing and running >Ruby applications and cannot be specified. For application dependency resolution and management, bundler is installed based on the contents of your Gemfile.lock. If you have a BUNDLED WITH in your Gemfile.lock then you will receive a different version of Bundler:
>
> Applications specifying Bundler 2.x in their Gemfile.lock will receive bundler: 2.0.1
> Applications specifying Bundler 1.x in their Gemfile.lock will receive bundler: 1.15.2
> Applications with no BUNDLED WITH in their Gemfile.lock will default to bundler: 1.15.2
> For more information on available settings see Bundler configuration. For more information on why we only support a specific set of bundler versions, please see this article about your Bundler version.

So it seems like [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#libraries) only allows certain versions of Bundler to be compatible, relevant doc is linked. Downgrade to 1.15.2 and give it another shot.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried to push the update to heroku I got this error     Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

Comment: rb-inotify-0.10.0 requires ruby version >= 2.2, which is incompatible with the
remote:        current version, ruby 2.0.0p648

Comment: oh, then try running all the commands again, but replace the bundler version 1.17.1 with 1.15.2. I saw something specific to Heroku for this, i'll see if I can find it

Answer (score 19):

Try to use

```rb
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
bundle _1.17.3_ install
```

Comment: The second of these commands alone, `bundle _1.17.3_ install`, fixed this issue for me

Comment: Yes, but _why_?? This shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: I you look closely the error also prints the instruction on how to fix it, in my case I had to: 
error: Install the necessary version with `gem install bundler:2.0.0.pre.3` and rerun bundler using `bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_ install`
fix: bundle _2.0.0.pre.3_ install
And worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall the newest version of bundler (especially if you have other applications).

First find the bundler version that you need. 
For example, after running `bundle install`:

```
Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (~> 4.2)', in any of the sources.
```

I need any version between 1.3.0 and  2.0. Hence, I would go for bundler 1.9.

Then, install the bundler:

```
gem install bundler -v 1.9
```

Run that bundler version to install gems:

```
bundler _1.9_ install
```