# How to bundle install gemfile with specific version of bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, bundler

I am trying to bundle install a project running `gem 'rails', '4.2.0'`.
Running `Bundle install`, I get :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.4)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 4.2.0)', in any of the sources.
```

Thus I then try to install bundler v 1.3.0 to successfully bundle this gemfile : `gem install bundler -v 1.3.0`

```
gem list bundler shows me that I successfully installed bundler at v 1.3.0
```

Then when trying to bundle install with v 1.3.0 like this `bundle _1.3.0_ install`, I get `Could not find command "_1.3.0_".`

How can I successfully run bundle install with that specific version of bundler ?

Comment: Try again to run `bundle install`.

Comment: nope that doesnt work cause it runs with my most recen version of bundler

Comment: Do you use rvm? If so make sure that you select a proper gemset with 1.3.0 version installed.

Comment: nope I use rbenv...

Comment: Have you considered using a separate environment for that project, such as Docker?

Comment: Something does not add up. I have bundler 2.1.4, and `bundle _1.3.0_ install` works after installing that version of the gem. Are there any bundler binstubs in the `bin` directory?

Comment: maybe you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901077/bundle-install-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler

Answer (score 23):

Basically, you need:

1. Bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0) installed on your local machine.
2. Ability to run that Bundler version.
3. Run that Bundler version to install other gems required by your app (bundle install).

First, check if you have successfully install Bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0) on your local machine:

```
$ gem list bundler
```

You should see:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (2.1.4, 1.17.3, 1.3.0)
```

If not, install it:

```
$ gem install bundler -v "<2" -N
# Install lasted bundler below version 2
# -N: No document
```

Second, check if you can run that Bundler version:

```
$ bundle _1.17.3_ -v
```

You should see:

```
Bundler version 1.17.3
```

If you installed Bundler 1.17.3 but cannot run "bundle *1.17.3* -v", there is something wrong with your RubyGems gem. Check if you installed updated version (latest is 3.1.3):

```
$ gem -v
```

Try to update the RubyGems gem, because it is the one help you run a specific gem version:

```
$ gem update --system
```

You should see:

```
Updating rubygems-update
...
Installing RubyGems 3.1.3
Successfully built RubyGem
    Name: bundler
    Version: 2.1.4
    File: bundler-2.1.4.gem
Bundler 2.1.4 installed
RubyGems 3.1.3 installed
Regenerating binstubs
...
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /home/lqt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/gem
    /home/lqt/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/bundle
...
RubyGems system software updated
```

Check again if you can run a specific Bundler version:

```
$ bundle _1.17.3_ -v
```

If you see:

```
Bundler version 1.17.3
```

Then, step 3, just run Bundler 1.17.3 to install other gems:

```
$ bundle _1.17.3_ install
```

Answer (score 3):

You can install *bundler* version 1.3 this way:

```
gem install bundler -v 1.3
```

And then use that specific version for installing gems:

```
bundle _1.3.0_ [install]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: As I explained in my post, unfortunately that doesnt work and spits Could not find command "_1.3.0_"

Answer (score 3):

you can try to add this to your Gemfile,

`gem 'bundler', '1.17.1'`

then try these commands:

```
gem install bundler -v 1.3.0
gem uninstall bundler -v 2.1.4
bundle update --bundler
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug with bundler previously, if you're using the wrong version of ruby gems. Try

```
gem update --system
```