# Bundler shows version I did not install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

I installed bundler with the command

```
gem install bundler --default -v 1.17.3
```

When I hit **gem lis**t, I get

```
bundler (default: 1.17.3)
```

But if I do bundler -v or bundler --version, I get

```
Bundler version 2.2.14
```

Which I did not install, so perhaps it was there before, or I have no idea.

The problem is I can't do bundle install because it gives me issues with the version, saying bundler > 2.0 isn't compatible with some of my gems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try this [Bundle install could not find compatible versions for gem “bundler”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901077/bundle-install-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-bundler)

Comment: Are you using RVM? This sounds to me like a PATH issue. Please add the outputs of `which gem` and `which bundler` to the question.